# WordPress - Getting ACF post_object inside wp_query

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Is it possible to use the `post_object` field inside custom `wp_query`? I created a template to list all blog posts and getting different content by getting a post_format. In one of the formats, I want to get `post_object` from Custom Post type that I was created. What I'm struggling with is getting ACF field values from that post, even if I pass the second parameter (ID) in `the_field()` it gets me always fallback, for example, for a date, it always showing me today's date.

Here is Query code:

```
$args = array(  
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish'
  );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
?>

     <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() ); ?>

<?php
        endwhile;

        wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
    <?php else : ?>
      <p><?php esc_html_e( 'There is no post to display' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

In `php` file of link format I'm checking if user check that he want to load post from CPT or to enter information manually. As you can see `HTML` and ACF fields are the same, just if user check that field, all content is loading from CPT

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
   <h4><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></h4>
 </a>
<?php 
if ( get_field( 'dafed_promo' ) == 1 ) :
  $post_object = get_field( 'choose_dafed' );
  if ( $post_object ):
     $post = $post_object;
     setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 

  <?php if ( have_rows( 'event_details' ) ) : ?>
     <?php while ( have_rows( 'event_details' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
      <div class="event-info">
         <p></p>
               <?php  // Load field value and convert to numeric timestamp.
                $unixtimestampdafed = strtotime( get_sub_field( 'event_time_and_date' ) );
             ?>
               <div class="date">
                <div class="month"> <?php echo date_i18n( "M", $unixtimestampdafed ); ?></div>
                <div class="number"><?php echo date_i18n( "d", $unixtimestampdafed ); ?></div>
              </div>

        <p>
          <strong>Vreme: </strong> <?php the_sub_field( 'event_time' ); ?><br>
          <strong>Lokacija: </strong><?php the_sub_field( 'event_location' ); ?><br>
          <strong>Organizator: </strong> <?php the_sub_field( 'event_organizer' ); ?>
        </p>
      </div>
      <span class="path"><strong><a>
       <?php echo get_the_author(); ?></a></strong> / <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>/ 
         <strong>
          <?php 
            $post_id  = get_the_ID();
            $post_categories = get_the_category( $post_id );
            foreach  ($post_categories as $category) {
              echo  '<a class="category-name">' . $category->cat_name . '</a> ';
            }
          ?>
       </strong>
       </span>
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-border">Pročitaj više</a>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>


<?php else : ?> 

  <?php if ( have_rows( 'event_details' ) ) : ?>
     <?php while ( have_rows( 'event_details' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
      <div class="event-info">
         <p></p>
               <?php  // Load field value and convert to numeric timestamp.
                $unixtimestamp = strtotime( get_sub_field( 'event_time_and_date' ) );
             ?>
               <div class="date">
                <div class="month"> <?php echo date_i18n( "M", $unixtimestamp ); ?></div>
                <div class="number"><?php echo date_i18n( "d", $unixtimestamp ); ?></div>
              </div>

        <p>
          <strong>Vreme: </strong> <?php the_sub_field( 'event_time' ); ?><br>
          <strong>Lokacija: </strong><?php the_sub_field( 'event_location' ); ?><br>
          <strong>Organizator: </strong> <?php the_sub_field( 'event_organizer' ); ?>
        </p>
      </div>
      <span class="path"><strong><a>
       <?php echo get_the_author(); ?></a></strong> / <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>/ 
         <strong>
          <?php 
            $post_id  = get_the_ID();
            $post_categories = get_the_category( $post_id );
            foreach  ($post_categories as $category) {
              echo  '<a class="category-name">' . $category->cat_name . '</a> ';
            }
          ?>
       </strong>
       </span>
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-border">Pročitaj više</a>
```

Comment: The get_sub_field method “returns the value of a specific sub field value from a Repeater or Flexible Content field loop” - are these actually _sub_ fields?

Comment: @04FS yes they are, because event_details is from field type group, it's not repeater